# How to write css media query based on control width instead of viewport width

Tags: css, media-queries

Is is possible to write css mediaquery based on control width instead of viewport width.

Example: If container min-width > 1000px set color=red and else set color=red using css ?  OR Instead of mediaquery, Is there any other way to achieve this scenerio ?

Answer (score 1):

CSS is not the proper tool for this job. It is not a scripting language and has very little functional use of [conditionals](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-conditional/). And that good! That's how it is supposed to be. Luckily we have JavaScript. JS makes it easy. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXCkg/2/)

```
<div style="width: 1000px" id="content">
   <h2>some title here</h2>
   <p>some content here</p>
</div>

<script>
var div = document.getElementById('content');
var el = div.style.width;
document.write ("SomeText");
if(el === '1000px')
{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
else
{
     document.body.style.backgroundColor="blue";
}
</script>
```

Keep in mind that this will break your style if a user has JavaScript turned off. Not a big deal but worth remembering.